# A not stateless Socket solution for NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets

I have to built a Client/Server application where the server side is just an application that passes data from one client to the other.

The client will be written in C# and I want to write the server in NodeJS, if that's possible. I'll try to explain the idea behind this.

It's best to explain this if you see this application as a 1vs1 game. So multiple clients can connect to an `Async` server. One client will be matched with another client as in a Player1 / Player2 context.

Player1 can make a "move". A `POCO` will be converted to a `JSON` format for example. That will then be send to the server and the server should know to what opponent (Player2) it should sent the data. Then in return Player2 can make a move and then new data will be send back through the server back to Player1.

So the server needs to have a list of all the connected players/clients. So it can keep track of what player play vs who and what scores they have etc. Basically, a stateless environment.

I've been thinking about writting the server in C# with the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` class. But since NodeJS/Socket.IO is already an optimized lib, that would save time if I could do it in that.

I just need to know if it's possible to do this in NodeJS. Or should I stick to a C# server?

Comment: hmm.. you mentioned that server needs to have list of all players etc. and keep track of scores.. that is not a stateless environment. :)

Comment: @MaunoV. That's why the title is "A **not** stateless Socket solution". So with other words it should NOT be stateless, as i believe NodeJS is now. So that's exactly what I'm asking for :)

Comment: Well. that is an easy job with nodejs I am currently writing my own multiplayer game to top of it but I am just unclear how you can open socket.io like connection through C#. That information I currently don't have for you.

Comment: @MaunoV. Well I guess TCP == TCP. regardless of what technology is involved. ALl I actually need to know is how to setup is stateful socket server in NodeJS. So if you have any resource for that, then that would at least point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey,

I argue that it is possible if you use something like [SocketIO4Net.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SocketIO4Net.Client) at your C# side to open connection to your node.js server.

From the docs:

> SocketIO4Net.Client can interact with Socket.IO instances in a very
>   similar manner as Socket.IO JavaScript clients. This project aims to
>   fill the JavaScript client and C# client gap for Socket.IO, and retain
>   a very similar application experience.

And for the purpose of storing player lists etc. at server, it is easy. You define javascript object just as `players` where you add your connected clients and use for example `socket.id` as identifier.

```
// Players currently at server
var players = {};
```

you do this usually by listening socket `connection` event, for example:

```
... somewhere in your code ...

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);

... somewhere in your code ...

// run on new client connection..
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {

    // adding to list of players you have in your server
    // Player can be your own declared class as you like it to be
    players[socket.id] = new Player({
        nickname: "playerNameExample"
    });

});
```

However, if your game is more like match-making 1vs1 it would be worth to consider that you add always your separate playing partners to different rooms in server. So exchanging messages travels only between relevant participants. See [socket.io rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms)

As for the resources where to go next: best choice is to just google "multiplayer game with socket.io" which will give wide variety of results. Just as this: [Building-multiplayer-games-with-nodejs](http://flippinawesome.org/2013/09/30/building-multiplayer-games-with-node-js-and-socket-io/) if you are completely new to node.js googling hello world with node.js might be better to do first.

Due note: If you don't know the basics and haven't tried programming anything with node.js you are not ready to make working multiplayer game, advance step by step.! ( and yes I am looking this now from game perspective as you instructed but behavior of games can be applied to many apps as well ). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. I know where to go from here :)